# Class does not name a type error

Tags: c++, class

I have the following code in a project:

```
    #ifndef MAP_H
    #define MAP_H

    #include <string>
    #include "MapCell.h"

    using namespace std;

    class Map{
    public:
        Map();
        Map(int, int);
        Map(string);
        virtual ~Map();
    private:
        int grid_size;
        MapCell * grid;

    };

    #endif
```

When I go to compile, I get the error "error: 'MapCell' does not name a type" yet when I comment out MapCell * grid and run this next block of code from main:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

#include "MapCell.h"

using namespace std;


int main() {

    MapCell * test_var;

    test_var = new MapCell();

    delete test_var;


    cout << "Press enter to end process...";
    cin.get();
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

everything works just fine. I know my MapCell.h and .cpp files are in the right places and I'm guessing the compiler can see them since it works from main. I read around some other questions and most answers seem to point to either syntax errors or forward declarations which don't really fit here (unless I'm overlooking something)

Any ideas on what's going on here?

Comment: Engaging my telepathy circuit... Projecting aura field... Scanning ESP interference patterns... Hm, sorry, no. Didn't work.

Comment: Oh, idea: it could maybe help to see the problematic header. As well as your build commands and search paths.

Comment: Okay, lemme guess then: you placed the declaration of `MapCell` in namespace `std`, yes? Or ... you include different headers called the same? Or ... you edited the header in the meantime?

Comment: @user3098124 : If I had to guess, if `MapCell.h` does indeed define `class MapCell`, then you probably accidentally put an `#ifndef MAP_H` in there instead of `#ifndef MAP_CELL_H`...

Comment: Please **never** ever put a using directive in a header.

Comment: Replace `#include "MapCell.h"` and  `using namespace std;` with `class MapCell;`.

Comment: Greatwolf I tried your solution and it worked out just fine. I am wondering if you would care to explain or point me to where I could get an answer as to why this works out the way it does. From my understanding I need the #include "MapCell.h" for the compiler to know that a MapCell class even exists. Also @chris mentioned to never use the using directive in a header. Why is that?

Comment: @MrJman006, Anyone who includes that header now gets stuck with the using directive. And it's not possible to tell without seeing the other header, but a forward declaration is all you need when delaring a pointer to it.

Comment: @chris This makes a lot of sense now. I do have one more question. does it matter if I use the using directive in the implementation file? As you say, it will not force a future user of my class to be stuck with anything if used in the implementation?

Comment: You can, it's just typically not recommended because of name clashes and readability.

Comment: @MrJman006 Just to emphasize @chris point, as the 'author' of your header file you should not be forcing that namespace on your clients. It is not your call whether they want to use a given namespace or not -- it should be theirs. So it is really bad etiquette for you to just *assume* everyone that's including your header wants `using namespace std;`.

Comment: @greatwolf That makes a lot of sense. I have background programming knowledge, but am working through really getting a handle on c++ and some of the concepts that may seem obvious are a little foreign to me as so much of these little caveats are taken care of by higher level languages. I really appreciate everyone's input!

Answer (score 1):

chris and greatwolf led me to the solution that fixed the problem. I needed to forward declare my MapCell class for the compiler to be able to link to the whole class.

Comment: An include *should* work unless there are circular dependencies, but a forward declaration is better if applicable.